Reactjs getting 401 error only at the first time
I am getting 401 error (mern stack project)only when i tap on the profile icon for the first time, but if i refresh the account page then all the datas are shown correctly.
This is the page in which i am showing the data
const { dispatch } = useContext(authContext);
  const [tab, setTab] = useState("bookings");

  const {
    data: userData,
    loading,
    error,
  } = useGetProfile(`${BASE_URL}/users/profile/me`);
  console.log(userData, "userdata");

  const handleLogout = () => {
    dispatch({ type: "LOGOUT" });
  };

  return (
    <section>
      <div className="max-w-[1170px] px-5 mx-auto">
        {loading && !error && <Loading />}
        {error && !loading && <Error errMessage={error} />}

This is my fetch data part from where i am getting the data.
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { token } from "../config";


const useFetchData = (url) => {

    const [data, setData] = useState([])
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
    const [error, setError] = useState(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            setLoading(true)
            try {
                const res = await fetch(url, {
                    headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` }
                })

                const result = await res.json()

                if (!res.ok) {
                    throw new Error(result.message + " Failed")
                }
                setData(result.data)
                setLoading(false)

            } catch (err) {
                setLoading(false)
                setError(err.message)

            }
        }

        fetchData()
    }, [url])



    return {
        data, loading, error
    };
};

export default useFetchData;


This the part where authentication is done
import { createContext, useEffect, useReducer,} from "react";

const initialState = {
  user: localStorage.getItem('user') !== undefined ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')) : null,
  token: localStorage.getItem('token') || null,
  role: localStorage.getItem('role') || null,
};

export const authContext = createContext(initialState);

const authReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "LOGIN_START":
      return {
        user: null,
        token: null,
        role: null,
      };
    case "LOGIN_SUCCESS":
      return {
        user: action.payload.user,
        token: action.payload.token,
        role: action.payload.role,
      };
    case "LOGOUT":
      return {
        user: null,
        token: null,
        role: null,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(authReducer, initialState);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(state.user));
    localStorage.setItem("token", state.token);
    localStorage.setItem("role", state.role);
  },[state]);

  return (
    <authContext.Provider
      value={{
        user: state.user,
        token: state.token,
        role: state.role,
        dispatch,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </authContext.Provider>
  );
};

At first i thought that maybe I am fetching the data in the wrong way but then i saw that its actually right, cause whenever i refresh the page again the data comes, also the data of the previous user also stays in the profile page even if a new user logins. The real data only comes when I refresh the page.
